# How to calculate minimum value of a function?

Tags: functions

How to calculate minimum value of a function?

$min $ $f(x)=(x_{1}-2)^2 + (x_{2}-1)^2 $

Comment: Hint a sum of squares is never negative. Then the question is, can it be zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that $\;x=(x_1,x_2)\;$ , and then

$$f(x)\ge 0\;\;\forall\;x\in\Bbb R^2\;,\;\;\;and\;\;\;\; f(2,1)=0$$

so...

Answer (score 2):

HINT : Note that 
$$(x_1-2)^2\ge 0,\ \ \ (x_2-1)^2\ge 0$$
for $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R$.